# How do I save an object using serializer from another serializer in django rest?

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I have two models, a parent and it's items

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    #fields

class ParentItems(models.Model):
    parentId = #parentId
    #fields
```

and want to create method **POST** `parent/` with ParentItems included, like

```
{
    "parentField": "value",
    "parentItems": [
        {
            "parentItemsField": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

So  I create `Parent` view using `ModelViewSet` and then the serializer:

```
class ParentItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #serializer

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parentItems = ParentItemSerializer(many=True, required=True, write_only=True)

    def _createParentItems(self, parentItem, parent):
        for item in parentItem:
            item['parent'] = parent.id
            parentItemSerializer = ParentItemSerializer(data=item)
            if parentItemSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                itemSerializer.save()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            parentItems = validated_data.pop('parentItems')
            createdData = super(ParentSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
            # create the parent item
            self._createParentItems(parentItems, createdData)
            return createdData
```

I add `parentItems` field in `ParentSerializer`, inside the `create` method I pop the `parentItems` and pass it into `_createParentItems` to create the items.

but this doesn't work, the parentItems is already an object. when I call `parentItemSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` it errors.

How do I save an object from another serializer in django rest? 
should I use another serializer field?

Tried using OrderedDict, it doesn't work, it didn't pass the items to `validated_data`

Answer (score 0):

First change your model like the following code. Then you can use serializer as I wrote for you.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    #fields

class ParentItem(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields


class ParentItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ParentItem
        fields = ('field1', ...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ParentItem.objects.create(field1=validated_data['field2'],...)
        return validated_data


class Parent(ModelSerializer):

    parentItems = ParentIremSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Parent
        fields = ('parentItems', 'other fields',...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        parent = Parent('field1'=validated_data['field1'])
        parent.save()

        parentItemsList = validate_data.pop('parentItems')
        parentItemSer = ParentItemSerialzer(data=parentItemsList,many=True)

        if parentItemSer.is_valid():
            parentItemSer.save()

       return validated_data
```

Comment: if I use `ParentItemSerialzer(data=parentItemsList,many=True)` the `data` is still in object form. it is a list of objects. I got a similar error like before.

Comment: Did you change your model as i said?

Comment: No it is not objects. it is still json

Comment: Yeah, I use ForeignField in my model. Maybe I miss something... I'll recreate the problem in a more smaller scope, I'll post as an update.

Comment: Is there a way to reuse the `parentItems` serializer (class variable from `Parent`) instead of creating a new serializer for each request?